# Write $\mathbb{Z}_{20}^{\times}$ as a product of p-power cyclic groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Can anyone let me know if my answer is okay?

> Write $\mathbb{Z}_{20}^{\times}$ as a product of p-power cyclic groups.

I showed that in general $\mathbb{Z}_{n}^{\times}=U(n)\leq \mathbb{Z}_{n}$, and since such a group is abelian and finite, $U(n)$ is abelian and finite by inheritance.

Then I applied the fundamental theorem of abelian finite groups, where $20=2^{2}\cdot 5$. Therefore, a product would be $U(20)=\mathbb{Z}_{4}\times \mathbb{Z}_{5}$. Is this product correct?

Comment: What is $U(n)$? I don't think you should be getting something of order $20$...

Comment: $\Bbb Z_{20}^\times$ does *not* have order $20$, it is pretty smaller. You have a lot of zero divisors there...

Comment: The order of $U(20)$ is $\phi(20) = \phi(2^2)\phi(5) = 2 \cdot 4 = 8.$ So, the product suggested $(\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_5)$ would certainly not work.

Comment: Thank you everyone for helping me. I realized my mistake from your helpful comments. :)

Comment: @user328442 I see! Then I can use $\mathbb{Z}_{2}^{3}$ as a product then?

Comment: That would have the correct order but still be wrong.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Oh really? Why is it wrong? Is it because it is only isomorphic?

Comment: No, because it will not be isomorphic to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right in saying that $U(n)$ is abelian, but for the wrong reasons: note that $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is a group with respect to $+$ whereas $U(n)$ is a group with respect to the product. In any case, $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is a commutative ring and so its group of unities will be an abelian group.

Your observation about the structure theorem is also somewhat correct, but not fully. Understanding $|U(n)|$ will give you useful information. Note that, in general,

$$
|U(n)| = |\{k : \operatorname{lcd}(k,n)  = 1\}| = \varphi(n)
$$

with $\varphi$ being Euler's function. In particular, $U(20)$ does *not* have twenty elements, it has eight. Thus, it is a $2$-group and by the structure theorem on abelian groups, it is one of the following:

$$
\mathbb{Z}_8 \ ; \ \mathbb{Z}_4 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 \ ; \ \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2. 
$$

Now, note that for example $3^2 = 9 \not \equiv 1 \pmod{20}$ and so not every element in $U(20)$ has order two. That discards $(\mathbb{Z}_2)^3$ because all of its elements have order two. In the same fashion, you can check that all elements are annihilated by $4$, i.e. $g^4 = 1$ for any $g \in U(20)$. Thus, there are no elements of order $8$ and in consequence,

$$
U(20) \simeq \mathbb{Z}_4 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2.
$$

Another way of seeing this is that given $x \in U(20)$,

$$
x^4 \equiv 1 \pmod{20}
$$

corresponds by the Chinese remainder theorem to a solution of

$$
\cases{x^4 \equiv 1  \pmod{4} \\ x^4 \equiv 1 \pmod{5}}
$$

and this is always the case: you can check by hand the case modulo $4$, and the other is a consequence of Fermat's little theorem.

Comment: Your solution is very clear and helps me understand very well my mistakes...thanks again for taking the time to help me. :)

Comment: No problem. I have a mistake in my last step, though: five is not coprime with $20$, and thus is not an element of $U(20)$. In any case, a similar calculation via orders of elements should tell which of the two remaining options is correct. I'll fix it asap :)

Comment: @numericalorange fixed!